# k8s network policy blocks DNS

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am trying to enable DNS for my pods with network policy.
I am using https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

When DNS works:

```
nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         100.64.0.10
Address:        100.64.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 100.64.0.1
```

with network policy

```
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I tried with

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: my_name
  namespace: my_namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: kube-system
    ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
```

or

```
egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:{}
      podSelector: {}
    ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
```

or

```
egress:
  - ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
```

None of them works. Only thing I tried which works, is following:

```
egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:{}
      podSelector: {}
```

But it opens all egress.

I tried those combination in my local k8s (minikube with cilium). All of them work as expected, but not in the production environment(AWS k8s 1.20 with calico ). I always have the DNS issue. From the tcpdump, I am sure the DNS is using port 53 with UDP.

I run out of ideas, please help~

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had same issue and adding following worked fine:

```
  egress:
    - ports:
        - port: 53
        - protocol: UDP
```

Answer (score 0):

the port is overwriten by the dns service to 8053.
the tcpdumper is running inside the pod, so it does not know it is re-routed .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).